# How to reverse a custom admin url in Django 1.5?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls

I want to add a custom url for a ModelAdmin but it seems Django changed template syntax in 1.5. I tried this way as the documentation pointed out but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
class VariableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_urls(self):
         urls = super(VariableAdmin, self).get_urls()
         my_urls = patterns('',
                       url(r'^settings/([A-Za-z0-9]*)', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.settings), name="settings"))
         return my_urls + urls

    def settings(self, request, category):
         return render_to_response('variables.html', {"opts": Variable._meta}))
```

Here is my variables.html

```
{% load admin_urls %}
{% url opts|admin_urlname:'settings' %}
```

This code throws an error like this:

`Reverse for 'common_variable_settings' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing name of the view to include application and model names:

```
...
my_urls = patterns('', url(r'^settings/([A-Za-z0-9]*)',
                   self.admin_site.admin_view(self.settings), 
                   name="common_variable_settings"))
...
```

The `admin_urlname` template filter returns "full" names, see it's source code:

```
@register.filter
def admin_urlname(value, arg):
    return 'admin:%s_%s_%s' % (value.app_label, value.module_name, arg)
```

So definitely You need to name Your view `"appname_modulename_settings"`. Maybe then try changing regular expression to something like this:

```
r'^settings/([A-Za-z0-9]+/)?$'
```

Comment: Actually I tried this way but it didn't work. I think this is not the expected behaviour though.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope it now helps!